# Uniform convergence of the series $\sum\limits_n \frac{\log(1+n^2x^2)}{n^2}$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Is the series $$\sum_1^\infty \frac{\log(1+n^2x^2)}{n^2}$$ uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$? I tried to use comparison test but unable to bound this by any convergent series. Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\log(1+n^2x^2)\leq \log(1+n^2)
$$
for $x\in [0,1]$ by monotonicity of the log. Use Weirstrass M-test to conclude.

edit: To see that the series 
$$
\sum\frac{\log(1+n^2)}{n^2}
$$
converges note that 
$$
\frac{\log(1+n^2)}{n^2}\sim \frac{\log n}{n^2}<\frac{n^\epsilon}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n^{2-\epsilon}}
$$
for any epsilon greater than zero and correspondingly large $n$ (a very useful fact about the logarithm). Probably going to want to select an $\epsilon<1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @qbert. It is very clear to me now.

Comment: Certainly. Good luck!

Comment: Please consider accepting if my answer resolved your question. Points for me and points for you

Comment: "Points for me and points for you" Decency?

Comment: @Did I'm sorry if you feel I was indecent. The incentive structure is there for a reason and clearly works as a motivator. Why beat around the bush?

Comment: Q.: "Why beat around the bush?" A.: See my previous comment.

Comment: @Did unclear as to what you mean

Comment: Sure about that? My impression is that, on the contrary, you are quite clear about the point but that you are using Evasion tactics 1.01 to avoid addressing it. Why not, I guess.

Comment: You didn't actually make any arguments. You said one word and quoted me twice. Your aim seemed more to mock me than make any point. I wanted you to clarify to avoid making an argument for you. Anyway, running this risk, no, decency to me does not mean pretending I'm not motivated in some large part by points on math stack exchange, a website I visit as a hobby. This is all not to mention that "points for me and points for you" is clearly meant to be funny and lighthearted.

Comment: You see? From the start, you were quite "clear as to what [I] mean[t]".